# Mjpeg in video containers use case

Tags: video, mkv

From time to time i'm converting mkv to mp4 using ffmpeg in order to save disk space. 
Currently i noticed that in some files multiple mjpeg streams where also included. Some of them were named `cover.jpg`.

From the name `cover.jpg` i assume that it is supposed to be displayed in some cases?!? But i never heard or saw that any program, eg. vlc, used an image to display anything from the video. So what is the use case of including pictures in a video file?

The files have one `normal` video stream, maybe multiple audio streams, and about 4 mjpeg streams.

Comment: Post the command you used.

Comment: It is in the video file, I didn't add it there. I don't understand the use case of it

Comment: mkv, like mp4 is a container format that is able to contain many different streams, including video, audio, subtitles, metadata and images. I'd guess that cover.jpg contains a poster image for displaying on a media playback system. BTW it's not the container format that dictates the size of the file. Mp4 isn't any more space efficient than mkv.

Comment: Never saw the cover.jpg in action on any kind of player. MP4 ist web playable, thats why I use this format instead of keeping it as mkv

Comment: Kodi and other media centres use cover.jpg to show the poster image in their menus. Where did the videos come from? https://www.matroska.org/technical/cover_art/index.html